# Zend Framerwork 1.9 populate checkbox from database query

Tags: php, arrays, database, zend-framework, checkbox

Using Zend framework 1.9. I have a table in db with many columns. I fetch only certain columns:

```
$select = $table->select();
$select->from($table, array('skill_id', 'description'))->where('parent_skill IS NULL');
$rows = $table->fetchAll($select);

print_r($rows->toArray());

//This is the output :
Array ( [0] => Array ( [skill_id] => 1 [description] => Soccorso stradale ) [1] => Array ( [skill_id] => 4 [description] => Carrozziere ))
```

Now I want to populate a checkbox element:

```
$form->skills->setMultiOptions ( $rows->toArray () );
```

My problem is the method `setMultiOptions` expect an array `array(key=>value)` . 
Is possible to convert my `$rows` array to a well formed array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to construct the array for options like this:

```
$row_options = array();
foreach($rows->toArray() as $key => $val){
    $row_options[$val['skill_id']] =  $val['description'];
}

$form->skills->setMultiOptions ($row_options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes you can i guess

```
    foreach($rows->toArray() as $subArray){
        foreach($subArray as $val){
            $newArray[] = $val;
        }
    } 
print_r($newArray);die;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use **fetchPair**:

......

$select->from($table, array('skill_id', 'description'))->where('parent_skill IS NULL');

$rows = $table->**fetchPair**($select);

$form->skills->setMultiOptions ($row_options);